# Notation for extracting value out of single element set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In some part of a document I am writing, I first define a set

$$
S : A \to \mathcal P(B) \\
S(a) =  \{ \text{complicated expression here using $a$} \}
$$

Later, I prove that $\forall a,~\exists x, ~S(a) = \{ x \}$.

So, I want to now construct some notation for referring to the set with a single element $\{ x \} \subset B$. Something like

$$unset(S(a))$$

where $unset$ is some valid definition / notation.

Comment: If $S(a) =\{x\}$ is guaranteed to be a singleton, then people will often abuse notation a bit by pretending that $S(a) = x$. In other words, both $x$ and $\{x\}$ are denoted as $S(a)$ (and hopefully the meaning is clear from context).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no commonly used notation specifically for this, so you shouldn't hesitate to just make up your own.  One way you can express it with standard notation is with the symbol $\bigcup$: if $S$ is a set, then $\bigcup S$ denotes the union of all the elements of $S$, so $\bigcup \{x\}=x$.  This is kind of a "hack" though and is not something you can expect your readers to effortlessly understand.  (Mathematically literate readers will figure it out, but it may take them a little work.)

Ultimately, the purpose of notation is to communicate, so you should pick your notation to communicate clearly and not be afraid to use words instead of notation if that would be clearer.  I would probably recommend instead just writing something like:

> We write $s(a)$ for the unique element of the set $S(a)$.

There's nothing special about the choice of $s$ as the function name for this; it's a reasonable choice to use to remind the reader that it is related to $S$ but there's nothing wrong with using a different name if you have a better reason.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose I'll just do that then :) I was hoping for some existing notation, but oh well.

Comment: I have doubts regarding the validity of blindly using this notation. I think that implicitly the union must be over a collection of *sets*. If not then what the heck would $2\cup \{3\}$ possibly mean?

Comment: @MPW Remember that $2=\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}$, so it's perfectly meaningful. :P (At least, if we're working in set theory.) More to the point, as long as the OP doesn't write "$\bigcup x$" when $x$ isn't a set, they'll be fine. And actually, even outside of ZFC you can arguably make sense of all such expressions: e.g. "$2\cup\{3\}$" is by definition $\{x: x\in 2$ or $x\in\{3\}\}$, and if $2$ has no elements this is just $\{3\}$. :P

Comment: @NoahSchweber : I can’t accept that. Here I refer to the union of a point (i.e. a non-set) with a set. That’s meaningless. I also do not accept the notion that $\{x\mid x\in y\}$ is meaningful if $y$ is not a set, so it certainly isn’t just $\varnothing$ because you can’t find any elements in $y$. The very notation is meaningless, just like writing “5 + banana” where “banana” really is a banana.

Comment: @MPW "Here I refer to the union of a point (i.e. a non-set) with a set." I know - I'm saying that "$x\in y$" *can* be viewed as making perfect sense even if $y$ isn't a set: if $y$ isn't a set, then no matter what $x$ is the statement "$x\in y$" is false. This is a perfectly coherent, if silly, way to approach things. And the ZFC approach moots the entire issue by making *everything* a set. But all this is beside the point, which is that this notation poses no danger to the OP: they're only writing "$\bigcup x$" in case $x$ is a set (namely, one of the $S(a)$s) so the issue won't even come up.

Comment: @NoahSchweber : I understand.

Answer (score 3):

It is just the union:

$$\bigcup S(a) = \bigcup\{x\} = x$$

Indeed, the union of a set $A$ is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union) with $$c \in \bigcup A \iff \exists D \in A \text{ such that } c \in D$$

For two sets we have the more familiar notation $A \cup B = \bigcup \{A,B\}$.

Comment: This is true but I wouldn't necessarily recommend actually using this notation--it is not particularly evocative of the desired meaning here and may confuse some readers.

Comment: @EricWofsey Agreed, I wouldn't use any kind of "$\text{unset}$" function. It would be best to state that $S(a) = \{x\}$ and then just use $x$.

Comment: This is neat, I would not have thought of that! However, I'm accepting Eric's answer, since I believe it answers the question's spirit better, by suggesting some kind of wording.

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you’re going to have to invent your own notation, why not just simply $\hat{a}$ ? Why bring $S$ into the notation at all?